# Deploying an osgi bundle (jsp hook) in liferay 7

Tags: osgi, liferay-7

Created an osgi bundle (jsp hook) in liferay. Using the server tab in Liferay Workspace environment, added the bundle to configured server.
Checked the osgi shell with

```
lb -s mytest.hook
START LEVEL 20
ID|State      |Level|Symbolic name
455|Installed  |    1|mystest.hook (1.0.0.201603221133)
```

The state is "Installed". Not sure how to proceed further in terms of the deployment. How will the State change to "Active" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it deployed successfully by actually putting it to the deploy folder, from which the Liferay's deployer kick's in and does the rest. So basically the deployer doesn't get notified when you do it from the server tab and add you project for deployment.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following command:

`start 455`

Probably your bundle does not resolve correctly. You should get a an exception that tells you the reason after calling start.

Comment: I did and then I get **start 455**
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Invalid operation on a fragment. and also for **resolve** 
Not all bundles could be resolved.

Comment: Ok .. so it is normal that start does not work on a fragment. Do you see any details after the resolve command? Maybe in the log?

Comment: diag 455
mytest.hook [455]
  Unresolved requirement: Fragment-Host: com.liferay.blogs.web; bundle-version="1.0.0"

Comment: Is the host bundle installed?

Comment: yes the host was 'active'. It seems to have something to do with the deployer in liferay. Will update the post indicating the solution