# Liferay 7 jsp hook module doesn't work

Tags: jsp, ide, liferay, laravel-blade, liferay-7

I tried to overwrite a JSP via Module. The module is deployt but it doesnt take any effect. I try to overwrite the create_account.jsp. My bnd.bnd looks like this:

`Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Fragment-Host: com.liferay.login.web;bundle-version="1.0.5"
-sources: true`

My Module is synchronized with the server. I use the developper-mode and Liferay 7.0.1 GA2.

The create_account.jsp is under the following path:

/test-module/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/create_account.jsp

Any ideas why it's not working?

The state of my portlet is **installed**. I can do the compileJSP taks and it changes to **resolved**. I think it should be **active** like all the other modules.

I also can't resolve the variables from the JSP, which are in other JSP-files. As example: **PropsValues**. Can it be, that there are wrong/missing dependencies in the **build.gradle**?
`dependencies {
    compile group: "com.liferay.portal", name: "com.liferay.portal.kernel", version: "2.0.0"
    compile group: "com.liferay.portal", name: "com.liferay.util.taglib", version: "2.0.0"
    compile group: "javax.portlet", name: "portlet-api", version: "2.0"
    compile group: "javax.servlet", name: "servlet-api", version: "2.5"
    compile group: "jstl", name: "jstl", version: "1.2"
    compile group: "org.osgi", name: "org.osgi.compendium", version: "5.0.0"
}`

i builded the hole project again without IDE and i get the same problem. When i try to deploy it a error happens. But it's still deployt on the server with the state **installed**.

```
PS C:\DEV\Git\faberplace-workspace\modules\com.clavisit.registration.hook.jsp> blade deploy
:modules:com.clavisit.registration.hook.jsp:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:modules:com.clavisit.registration.hook.jsp:buildCSS UP-TO-DATE
:modules:com.clavisit.registration.hook.jsp:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:modules:com.clavisit.registration.hook.jsp:transpileJS SKIPPED
:modules:com.clavisit.registration.hook.jsp:configJSModules SKIPPED
:modules:com.clavisit.registration.hook.jsp:classes UP-TO-DATE
:modules:com.clavisit.registration.hook.jsp:jar
:modules:com.clavisit.registration.hook.jsp:assemble
:modules:com.clavisit.registration.hook.jsp:build

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 5.486 secs
stop 482
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Invalid operation on a fragment.
update 482 file:/C:/DEV/Git/faberplace-workspace/modules/com.clavisit.registration.hook.jsp/build/libs/com.clavisit.regi
stration.hook.jsp-1.0.4.jar
Updated bundle 482
start 482
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Invalid operation on a fragment.
Error
  0. [DeployCommand.installOrUpdate] aQute/bnd/header/Parameters
```

When i copy the JAR after the **blade deploy** into the deploy folder, the state changes to **resolved**.

It's the same problem as here:
[Deploying an osgi bundle (jsp hook) in liferay 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36157832/deploying-an-osgi-bundle-jsp-hook-in-liferay-7/36180179#36180179)

**Further Informations:**

I work on windows.

The log says the follwing when i deploy:

```
07:05:43,732 INFO  [com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployScanner][AutoDeployDir:252] Processing blade.hook.jsp-1.0.0.jar
07:05:51,904 INFO  [Refresh Thread: Equinox Container: b0a1d0af-1044-0016-189b-a4fba6a2d683][BundleStartStopLogger:38] STOPPED com.liferay.login.web_1.0.5 [219]
07:05:52,494 INFO  [Refresh Thread: Equinox Container: b0a1d0af-1044-0016-189b-a4fba6a2d683][BundleStartStopLogger:35] STARTED com.liferay.login.web_1.0.5 [219]
```

And it Looks like the following picture:

[Login Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiC02.png)

Answer (score 0):

A fragment is never activated. It's attached to the host module at the time when the host module is resolved. It sounds like one of the problems you have is solved by manually copying your fragment JAR to Liferay's `deploy` folder, right? One thing you could to to make sure the fragment attaches to the host is, from the gogo shell, type *refresh [host bundle id]*. Not entirely certain, but that should make the host pick up the fragment.

Additionally, check out the `blade.hook.jsp` sample here: https://github.com/liferay/liferay-blade-samples/tree/master/gradle/blade.hook.jsp

The `build.gradle` file has only the version set to 1.0.0, and the `bnd.bnd`, in addition to what you have in yours, includes

```
-jsp: *.jsp,*.jspf
-plugin.jsp: com.liferay.ant.bnd.jsp.JspAnalyzerPlugin
```

I'd start there.

Edit to address comment:
I tested the [liferay-blade-samples](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-blade-samples) fragment project from the command line by doing the following:

1. Navigate to the liferay-blade-samplesclone and into gradle/blade.hook.jsp and build the project.
2. Copy the JAR into my running Liferay CE GA2 installation's `deploy` folder. I see this in the log:

`15:26:51,185 INFO  [com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployScanner][AutoDeployDir:252] Processing blade.hook.jsp-1.0.0.jar
15:26:59,253 INFO  [Refresh Thread: Equinox Container: 10c85452-c442-0016-189b-ada8a71b73c4][BundleStartStopLogger:38] STOPPED com.liferay.login.web_1.0.5 [171]
15:26:59,659 INFO  [Refresh Thread: Equinox Container: 10c85452-c442-0016-189b-ada8a71b73c4][BundleStartStopLogger:35] STARTED com.liferay.login.web_1.0.5 [171]`

The JSP just does this:

`<p style="color: red">changed</p>`

And I can see the red text "changed" when I sign out of Liferay and then click *Sign In*. Does that work for you?

Comment: Thank you Russ Bohl
With the Refresh is a nice way to change the status from installed to resolved. I added the 2 lines but it doesn't change anything. I also tried to build 2 sample project, but they didn't  work for me either. Any ideas?

Comment: I edited my question. My log looks like yours but the login looks like without hook. On which OS do you work? I work on windows

Comment: It worked on a Linux server on GA 1 i have to check if the problem is the version or the OS...

Comment: I found out on a Liferay 7.0.1 GA 2 it doesn't work, but it works on a GA 1. The only thing I changed was the com.liferay.login.web version in the bnd.bnd file

Comment: I'm on Linux but I can't see how that would make a difference here. One interesting thing: the Liferay Blade Sample project has this in the `bnd.bnd`: `Fragment-Host: com.liferay.login.web;bundle-version="1.0.0"
` And the JAR fragment I build from the source works properly on  both GA1 and GA2 for me.

Comment: Maybe there is a problem with the blade build on windows :/

Comment: Hmm, try specifying a range of versions for the host, I don't remember exactly but I think the syntax is [1.0,1.1) or something like that.

Comment: I m working on windows and trying for module fragment for searh jsp but it is not working, please help me thanks